# Where is the Gold Slaad mentioned?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, dnd-3e, product-identification

One of the various species of monsters created for D&D is the Slaad — vicious, large bipedal 'frog-beings' native to the plane of Limbo, that diverge into various subspecies based on color — red, blue, green, grey and black (or Death Slaad).

I vaguely remember reading somewhere about a unique “Gold Slaad” being with godlike or near godlike power… but I can't recall where. I thought I saw it in the 3e Manual of the Planes but I have been unable to find it there (at least in the Limbo section). Is this being familiar to anyone?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are thinking of **[Ssendam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssendam)**, the Slaadi **Lord of Madness** detailed in the 1st edition Fiend Folio and Manual of the Planes. He appears as a golden slaad in his golden castle in Limbo near the slaadi Spawning Stone, but normally looks like a huge amoeba. He is the oldest of the slaadi lords, believes that madness is the ultimate form of chaos, and doesn't care about making friends with other slaadi.

Ssendam gets a huge power boost in 2nd edition, from Dragon Magazine #211, going from a modest 197 hit points to 41,251 (as well as a sex change to female, among other things). She disappears in 3rd edition, and seems to have been written out of 4th, as the Spawning Stone is now guarded by a being known as the Guardian of the Stone.

There is an unrelated Golden Slaad in the 4th edition Monster Manual 3 (page 178) that is much weaker ("only" level 20). It seems to have been inspired by Ssendam, as it will turn amorphous when reduced to half of its hitpoints, and has the same dismissive attitude towards the slaadi that worship it.